# error al consultar una tabla con nombre algo$algo

Tags: php, oracle, sql

Tengo una consulta similar a esto:

```
select * from nombre$tabla where valor = 1;
```

Si ejecuto esto en mi motor de bd funciona (Oracle), pero cuando corro esto desde PHP no me devuelve registros, el código en php lo estoy mandando así:

```
$query = "select * from nombre\$tabla where valor = 1"

$conection  = self::DbOracle();        
$sql = $conection->prepare($query);          
$sql->execute();        
$resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
```

¿Alguien ha hecho algo parecido? Obviamente no puedo cambiar el nombre de la tabla

PD: Ya intente igual pasar el nombre de la tabla como una variable concatenando el string y tampoco me devuelve valores

Comment: Ya detecte el problema, tenía un error en parte de mi consulta que estaba ocasionando que no me devolviera ningún registro.  Ya se puede considerar cerrada esta pregunta. :)

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar tu consulta de la siguiente forma para pasar el table name en variable :

```
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';

try {
   $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
   echo "<h2>Base de Datos CODINGGROUND Conectada<h2>";
}catch(PDOException $e){
   echo "<h1>" . $e->getMessage() . "</h1>";
}
$mysql_tb = 'users';

$sql ="SELECT * FROM `{$mysql_tb}`";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```